# How to get count of unique values of all variables in dataframe in R

Tags: r, variables, unique, categories, distinct

I have data frame in R of 110 variables. I want to get count of distinct categories in each of them.

I know there is option to check one at the time: lenght(unique(dataframe$x)), but i want to get table with count of unique values for 110 variables. I guess its programming problem, i dont know how to refer to every of them

length(unique(dataframe[,1:ncol(dataframe)]))
i tried this but not working

i expect to get 2x110 table  with the count of unique values in each variable

Comment: Try `sapply(dataframe, function(x) length(unique(x)))`

Comment: `library(tidyverse)` wide: `iris%>%summarise_all(n_distinct)` or long: `iris%>%summarise_all(n_distinct)%>%gather()`